# How To Set Up common one Nginx Server Blocks (Virtual Hosts) for all peojects in Centos

Tags: apache, nginx, centos, wampserver

I have a Centos with Nginx server and multiple site folders are exist in wamp.

But for every project i should need to write separate Nginx server blocks under /etc/nginx/conf.d/websites.conf file. So whenever i created a new project then after i have to add below lines under websites.conf file of Nginx.

```
location /project-folder {
        root path;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        rewrite ^/project-folder/(.*)$ /project-folder/app/webroot/$1 break;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /project-folder/app/webroot/index.php?q=$uri&$args;

        location ~ .*\.php$ {
            include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:xxxx;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
        location ~* /project-folder/(.*)\.(css|js|ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
            root path/project-folder/app/webroot/;
            try_files /$1.$2 =404;
        }

    }
```

So is it any other way to make a common block for all site-folder and doesn't need to add new server block for new site?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the `path` common to all projects? And what is `/` used for (or any URI which is not in a project folder)?

Comment: Yes thanks Richard, all projects have same common path and existing under websites folder. Also i have added separate entry of Nginx server blocks under Nginx 's websites.conf file then i am accessing each project with domain-name/project-foldername. So i just want to know is it possible to add common entry for all projects under Nginx config file, so i don't need to add this under config file of Nginx after creation of new project.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to implement this. If you are using multiple domain names, you can use a regular expression in the `server_name` to create named captures (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#regex_names) for more). You can use a regular expression in the `location` directive to capture the value of *project-folder* (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for more).

The main function of this configuration is to insert the text */app/webroot* between the project name and the remainder of the URI. The challenge is to do it without creating a redirection loop.

I have tested the following example, which works by placing a generalised version of your `rewrite` statement into the `server` block and capturing the project name for use later in the one of the `try_files` statements:

```
server {
    ...

    root /path;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    rewrite ^(?<project>/[^/]+)(/.*)$ $1/app/webroot$2;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ $project/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
    location ~ .*\.php$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:xxxx;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
    location ~* \.(css|js|ico|gif|png|jpg|jpeg)$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
    }
}
```